# How to get a user's privileges?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I can get the logged in user's privileges in powershell like so:

```
whoami /priv
```

How do I do this for a user I'm not logged in as?

Comment: Do you want this for someone who _is_ currently logged in, or for just any user in general?

Comment: Any user.  I'd like to do something like: whoisuser someuser /priv.  If you get my drift.

Answer (score 6):

This might answer for your question.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922

Via AccessChk, you should be able to view all users and their associated rights on that 2008  Server. (Sysinternals)

Comment: I'd rather the tool already be installed with the operating system.

Comment: ...which is often not possible under Windows; the recommended toolkits are often not so much recommended as much as mandatory (or WHY THE @#%!! DIDN'T THEY INCLUDE THEM?!)

Comment: @subt13 What Bart said.  Alternatively wait 3-5 years and MS may include those toolkits with the OS (and you'll be able to download newer, better ones).

Answer (score 3):

SECEDIT /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg foo.txt exports the list of user privileges and the users associated with each of the privileges.

Since this returns the set of user privileges associated with all the users associated with the system where the command gets executed you will have the information for any user associated with the system whether or not he/she is logged in.

The /areas is for you to specify the information that you are interested in that needs to be exported. (to the file specified following /cfg).

You have options for  /areas as SECURITYPOLICY/GROUP_MGMT/USER_RIGHTS/REGKEYS/FILESTORE/SERVICES

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to put this here as an answer for another way of doing it, even though I haven't learned enough about this tool to really understand the output ):

```
secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg foo.txt
```